# android:layout_marginTop in the drawer menu?

Tags: android, xml, layout, slidingdrawer

I downloadet a template and I have this problem:
https://gyazo.com/5161740a619bacb8aa8bd430a3e40b2d

The "Inbox" button is too close to the top and it looks bad.
I want to set a marginTop from 10dp, is that possible?

Here is my "drawermenu.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <item android:title="Inbox"
          android:id="@+id/nav_item_inbox"
          android:icon="@drawable/inbox" />

    <item android:title="Sent"
          android:id="@+id/nav_item_sent"
          android:icon="@drawable/sent"/>

    <item android:title="Drafts"
          android:id="@+id/nav_item_draft"
          android:icon="@drawable/draft"/>



    <item android:title="Others">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:title="Spam"
                android:icon="@drawable/spam"/>
            <item
                android:title="Bin"
                android:icon="@drawable/bin"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <group android:id="@+id/group_settings_id">

        <item android:title="Settings"
              android:icon="@drawable/settings"/>
        <item android:title="Help"
             android:icon="@drawable/help"/>
    </group>


</menu>
```

Comment: have you tried it

Comment: @meda yes I did

Comment: Show the xml file where you added drawerlayout please.

Comment: Oh ^^ That was the solution, I added marginTop to the drawerLayout properties.